# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in Playsound module

Tags: python, gtts

Hello I have made a code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import playsound
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
u = raw_input('type: ')

def player(textg):
    tts = gTTS(text = textg, lang='en')
    tts.save('name.mp3')
    playsound('name.mp3')
player(u)
```

An error comes that:

```
playsound('name.mp3')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Please Help Me, i am using Python2.7.15

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the whole module, not a method within it.

You'd need to do something like

```
from playsound import playsound
```

case your method is called `playsound`

Answer (score 0):

you should either import  the specific method or call playsound method of the playsound module that you imported already:

```
playsound.playsound('name.mp3')
```

Comment: it is a pleasure.